# Cannot retrieve results from Bamboo using REST API

Tags: rest, bamboo

I am trying to build result information from an Atlassian hosted instance of Bamboo using the REST API, but have hit a roadblock almost immediately.

Trying to get the result information for a specific plan I would expect the following URL to return a result set:

- https://mydomain.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/result/PROJECT-PLAN

Where PROJECT-PLAN has been copied from the UI URL for the given plan:

- https://mydomain.atlassian.net/builds/browse/PROJECT-PLAN

This is based on the documentation here:

- https://developer.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOODEV/Bamboo+REST+Resources#BambooRESTResources-BuildService—SpecificPlan

However, when I try to retrieve this through my browser (authenticated, with access to the UI URL), I get the following response:

```
<status>
  <status-code>404</status-code>
  <message>
     null for uri: https://mydomain.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/result/SFDC-AQB
  </message>
</status>
```

I fear I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that my base URL was directing me to the JIRA REST API, rather than Bamboo:

Adding "builds" into the URL solves the problem.

- https://mydomain.atlassian.net/builds/rest/api/latest/...